# Entering natural language input in WolframScript

Tags: scripting, natural-language, free-wolfram-engine

What is the equivalent of typing <kbd>=</kbd> at the beginning of a line to specify [natural language input](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/natural-language-input/) in WolframScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using [Interpreter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InterpretingStrings.html) with [SemanticExpression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/SemanticExpression.html):

```
Interpreter["SemanticExpression"]["population of Switzerland"]
```

It can also be done using [SemanticInterpretation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticInterpretation.html) (thanks *@Bob Hanlon*):

```
SemanticInterpretation["population of Switzerland"]
```

Comment: Or `SemanticInterpretation["population of Switzerland"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to make an alias so there is no need to type the whole function?

Comment: `sem[str_String] := SemanticInterpretation[str]`; however, the autocompletion essentially does this.

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't think there is any autocompletion in the [WolframScript command line interpreter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html). I think your comments are worth a full answer.